# Log4j2.xml - Queue size and discardingThreshold

Tags: asynchronous, queue, log4j2, logback, rollingfileappender

how can we specify the queue size and discardingThreshold for Asynchronous appenders in log4j2.xml

Below is sample snippet from logback.xml.

```
 <appender name="appender1" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
     <queueSize>500</queueSize>
     <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
     <appender-ref ref="one" />
    </appender>
```

I need to implement similar functionality in log4j2.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the queue size on property bufferSize of AsyncAppender.

> log4j2.yaml

```
Configuration:
  appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: %d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%-5p] %c{36} - %m%n
    Async:
      name: ASYNC-CONSOLE
      bufferSize: 1
      blocking: false
      AppenderRef:
        ref: CONSOLE
      ...
```

or

> log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%-5p] %c{36} - %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <Async name="ASYNC-CONSOLE" bufferSize="1">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </Async>
  </Appenders>
  ...
```

With other property, discardingThreshold, this behavior on log4j2 is log synchronously going direct to appender when the queue is full, you can set the propertiess log4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy with "Discard", in other words, log4j since 2.10, doesn't discard events by default, like      `<discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>` on logback.

See [log4j2 docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncQueueFullPolicyFactory.html).